# Found error while starting Ripple server..as unhandled St13runtime_error 'Unable to open/create RocksDB

Tags: ripple

I installed ripple server on ubuntu machine after when I goes to start through command line with command 
opt/ripple/bin/rippled --conf=/etc/opt/ripple/rippled.cfg

then found error as 
Terminating thread rippled: main: unhandled St13runtime_error 'Unable to open/create RocksDB: IO error: lock /var/lib/rippled/db/rocksdb/rippledb.86c2/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable'

and How I ensure that my ripple server is fully synced?

Comment: foudn any solution because i am facing the same isse

Comment: yes, found this solution.. you can run with sudo this command. its working